# NumberFormatException in Kotlin (IntelliJ)

Tags: kotlin, variables, intellij-idea, nullpointerexception, integer

Here is what I am trying to do, I want the user to enter whatever number and it should be displayed, but I am getting this error.
import java.util.*

This is my code

```
fun main(){
print("Enter your age")
var age = readLine()!!.toInt()
print(age)
}
```

And the error I am getting is

```
Enter your age 40
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: " 40"
at java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:67)
at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:654)
at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:784)
at HelloKt.main(Hello.kt:5)
at HelloKt.main(Hello.kt)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: @IvoBeckers corrected sir

Comment: Also, use `readln()` instead of `readLine()!!`, it's meant for forgetting about the `null` you would get on EOF

Comment: That is not a `NullPointerException`. I edited the title to fix it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are writing a space in front of the 40 as indicated by the error " 40".

A solution could be is to trim all leading and trailing whitespaces from the readLine, like this:

```
var age = readLine()!!.trim().toInt()
```